# Is there any way to update configuration (Description) of all Jenkins jobs in one shot without doing it manually?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have multiple Jenkins job running in prod and need to update Config (Description) of all jobs in one shot.How to do that without doing manually ? 
I need to update specific pattern for each job i.e. all http should replace with https only.

Comment: have you tried by writing script which will edit the config file of each job? After just using reload config its can reflect in jenkins.

Comment: You can start using DSL script in your jenkins. This could be your first step to automate it.

Comment: I think Configure Slicing Tool can does the job but is supports so many functions, i am confused which one will be useful in my case.